# How can force-free magnetic fields have current parallel to magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction, plasma-physics

We know that for a [force-free magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-free_magnetic_field), $\vec{J} \times \vec{B} = 0$, which means that the current should be parallel to the magnetic field that is creating it. However, from Ampère's law $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} = \mu_{0}\vec{J}$, so I would expect that the current would rotate in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction around the magnetic field.
How is it that the current is parallel to the magnetic field?

Comment: What is a force free magnetic field ? And who is "we"?

Comment: @my2cts Force free magnetic field:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcefree_magnetic_field . And we is me and the rest of the people that study physics

Comment: So @Jokerp is the reference? Btw there's a mistake in your link.

Comment: My guess (so not an answer) is that there is a magnetic field component perpendicular to the current but in the low pressure limit this is neglected. Also the reference in the very terse and puzzling wikipedia article is a dead link to some web page. Are you sure this is mainstream physics?

Comment: @my2cts I guess ... Chandrashekar wrote a paper on this http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1957ApJ...126..457C

Comment: So "we" is actually Chandrasekar.

Comment: @my2cts We is I would say the plasma (astro)-physics community. Force free magnetic field is a term that you will often hear in the field

Comment: It is quite well explained on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-free_magnetic_field), what is your question?

Comment: @AFG I think my question is clear

Comment: @Jokerp I can't see any question, I just see that you expect something that is not compatible with $\vec{J}\times\vec{B}=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which means that the current should be parallel to the magnetic field that is creating it.

I am not sure if this was intentional or just a misphrased statement, but currents are the sources of fields, not the converse.  In the case of a magnetic field-aligned current, there is usually an external source (e.g., planetary magnetic field) and the field-aligned current is locally generated (e.g., magnetic field-aligned beam of one particle species, not both).

> However from Maxwell's law $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_{o} \mathbf{j}$ so I would expect that the current would rotate in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction around the magnetic field.

Again, recall that the source of the field is something like a current or some net magnetization due to atomic/particle spins.  For this reason, a magnetic field-aligned current will locally cause a perturbation in a *background* magnetic field, caused by something like a planetary body, that does curl about the *background* magnetic field.  It would look kind of like the circuit drawing for an inductor, where the "coiled up" part would exist where the magnetic field-aligned current exists.

> We know that for a force-free magnetic field $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} = 0$.  Which means that the current should be parallel to the magnetic field that is creating it.

Returning to the second statement here, you can can construct a scenario where the current is not parallel to the background magnetic field.  That is, let the following be true:  $B_{z} = B_{y} = B_{o}$, $B_{x} = 0$, $j_{z} = j_{y} = j_{o}$, $j_{x} = 0$.  We also linearize so that quantities obey the following $Q = Q_{o} + \delta Q$, where $Q_{o}$ are static terms and $\delta Q$ is a fluctuating term that can depend upon time or space.  In this way, we don't violate [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) in the linear limit and still satisfy $\delta \mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} = 0$, i.e., a force-free field without magnetic field-aligned currents.